# Symfony create component : sfConfigurationException The component does not exist

Tags: php, configuration, symfony1, components

I am new at symfony and I'm getting an error when creating a new component :

> 500 | Internal Server Error |
>   sfConfigurationException The component
>   does not exist: "etatFlotte",
>   "results".

I followed the steps in http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0 ... ayer#Slots to build my component.

My module name is etatFlotte
In my component.class.php

I have this :

```
class etatFlotteComponents extends sfComponents
{

public function executeResults(sfWebRequest $request){


}

}
```

In my module/templates/_results.php , I have some html.

Now in the module where I want to display the component modules/resume/templates/indexsuccess.php, I have the code :

include_component('etatFlotte', 'results')

I should not get any errors but I'm getting the component does not exist error. I tried adding to the view.yml :

```
components:
etatFlotte: [etatFlotte, results]
```

But nothing....
Could somebody help me ? I really want to know how to create a component and make it work. I think I have missed some configuration steps somewhere.vchellen

Comment: Did you get Jobeet up and running fine? That tutorial pretty much goes through each step to ensure all configurations are correct for development. Plus the added benefit of learning the very basics to do what you are trying. I wish I had a better answer for you : )

Comment: You should be learning 1.4. 1.0 is old and not being maintained anymore. Also: the filename should be `compontents.class.php`, not `component.class.php`.

Comment: Maerlyn means `components.class.php`

Comment: D'oh, thanks. Can't edit it now.

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly have invoked incorrectly? Too frequently, this mistake happens,

```
include_component('module/componentName', $paramsArray)  // this is wrong
```

Should be,

```
include_component('module', 'componentName', $paramsArray)
```